Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'
was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
infos
"react-native": "0.70.0",


I am getting error on the version of Kotlin, I`ve change the version but still the same

Please [edit] your question and replace your screenshots with text so that we can easily copy it. Also please make sure that the code you provide suffices as a [mre].
